# Create Table SQL Server where column name is select colName from another table

Tags: sql-server, database, create-table

I am designing a table which contain 90 plus columns.

Let's say table name is `table_fromCol`. All these columns name are values for same column in a table.

Let's say table `table_colName` contains:

```
id    colName
-----------------
1     Price
2     Quantity
3     Vat
4     Custom Duty
5     Maximum Price
6     Discount
```

I want to create table with all those columns name.

Now create a table `table_fromCol`

Its design view is :

```
Columns       datatype      null
----------------------------------
id             int          false
Price          varchar      true
Quantity       varchar      true
Vat            varchar      true
Custom Duty    varchar      true
Maximum Price  varchar      true
Discount       varchar      true
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you tried so far and let us know the problems you run into?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If you have columns like `Price` or `Quantity` - **do NOT** store them as `varchar`! This is a **horribly bad design practice!**

Comment: sorry i have not done any yet i am just reading tutorial if it is possible @cristik
yeah i know that here and thnks for reminding me -marc

Thank you both for comnt

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot and "select into" to generate the table.

Or, You can use T-SQL to write a short script and create the table for you like this:

```
declare c cursor fast_forward for select colname from table_colname;
declare @cname varchar(50), @sql varchar(1000);
select @sql='create table table_fromcol (id int';
open c;
fetch from c into @cname;
while @@fetch_status=0 begin
   select @sql=@sql +','+@cname+' varchar(50)';
   fetch next from c into @cname;
end;
select @sql=@sql+')';
print @sql;
exec(@sql);
deallocate c;
```

you can edit the code to change the column type, size in the new table.